# convergence of an integral ( with an inner integral)

Tags: integration, convergence-divergence

I need to figure out for which values of $p \in R $ does the following integral converge?

$$\int_0^{1} \frac{x^p}{\int_0^{x}\ln(1 + \sin(t) + t)dt} {dx} $$

Please note that I don't have to calculate anything, just to prove convergence. In addition, I may use Riemann or Dirichlet tests to prove it.

Thank you for your help!

In addition, I need to figure out whether the following converges, where the limits of integration have changed but the integrand is the same:

$$\int_1^\infty \frac{x^p}{\int_0^{x}\ln(1 + \sin(t) + t)dt} {dx} $$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the first question, just note that $\log(1 + t + \sin t) = 2t + O(t^2)$, so that

$$F(x) = \int_{0}^{x} \log (1 + t + \sin t) \, dt = x^2 + O(x^3) $$

near $x = 0$. Also, since the integrand is positive for $t > 0$, we have $F(x) > 0$ for $x > 0$. Thus

$$ \int_{0}^{1} \frac{x^p}{F(x)} \, dx \text{ converges} \quad \Longleftrightarrow \quad \int_{0}^{1} x^{p-2} \, dx \text{ converges}. $$

Therefore we must have $p-2 > -1$, or equivalently $p > 1$.

For the second question, note that $\log t \leq \log(1 + t + \sin t) \leq \log (3t)$ for $t > 1$. That is, we have the asymptotic relation

$$F(x) = x \log x + O(x) \quad \text{as } x \to \infty. $$

So we find that

$$ \int_{1}^{\infty} \frac{x^p}{F(x)} \, dx \text{ converges} \quad \Longleftrightarrow \quad \int_{2}^{\infty} \frac{x^{p-1}}{\log x} \, dx \text{ converges}. $$

Now it is not hard to show that the latter converges if and only if $p-1 < -1$, or equivalently, $p < 0$.

Comment: Great answer, you've helped me alot! thank you !

Comment: @sos44o can you explane more why does $$F(x) = x \log x + O(x) \quad \text{as } x \to \infty.$$ ?

Comment: @eyal, Note that $$ \int_{1}^{x} \log t \, dt \leq F(x) - F(1) \leq \int_{1}^{x} (\log t + \log 3) \, dt. $$ Since $\int \log t \, dt = x \log x - x + C$, the conclusion follows.